# Logging framework with performance in mind

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I want to design a logging framework, a simple one with emphasis on performance.

Now, if an application have multiple threads (say 1000 threads at a time), and if we code like this:

```
MyLogger logger; // Assuming singleton logger for the entire application
```

When a thread want to log into file, there may be chances multiple thread too want to, hence I think of this synchronization:

```
synchronized(logger) {
    // thread does the logging into file
}
```

But this approach isn't efficient as it enforces sequential access.

I read about `java.util.concurrent.*` and I was hoping if this can help, I see there we have lock concept `lock.tryLock()`, but even then this won't help.

Is there any other way in which multiple thread can write to log file without affecting each other's data which they are writing into the file?

Comment: You might want to consider not writing your own, but just using one of the existing logging frameworks. If you do decide to write your own, then maybe you should look how other open-source logging frameworks solve this. In any case, although an interesting question, this is probably too broad.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks for your reply, but how does a framework (like log4J) perform exceptionally well ? I am looking inputs for those points. Anything that you can share?

Comment: Log4j is open source, if you want to know, you'll need to study their sources.

Answer (score 2):

I would make logger a class which has a queue for items to be logged. When a class use this logger like, `logger.error` I would add the contents to the log queue.

Logger class should also have its own thread waiting an item to be added to the queue, when an item is added, it should pop this item from queue and logs it to the file. (You can use publish-subscribe here). The queue should be thread safe like `BlockingQueue` variants. If you are not just logging strings(or immutable objects), you also have to be sure, objects that are passed to the log method should not be changed(you may have to clone it before adding to the queue). If you choose the clone path, you have to consider to not to fill up memory quickly.

If you can use external library log4j2 has async log ability, which should offer great performance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, regardless of which way you synchronize the threads and the access to the logger in your java code, you still have the physical bottleneck of writing all log statements into the same file, which can only be done sequentially.

The solution is to use a publish / subscribe mechanism, where the logging calls only publish the log statements into a common queue. The statements are written to the log file by a single thread, which consumes the statements from the queue.

This way you only need to synchronize the calling threads around putting elements into the queue, which is a quick, inexpensive operation. You would not want to synchronize threads around writing into a file, which is much slower and would lead to a much higher overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lock and performing I/O operation inside lock will heat performance.In my opinion create a buffer to which all log message will store and a separate thread will process batch by batch.Here also while putting to the queue multiple thread we need synchronization.One optimization comes to my mind is partition.Partition the queue and calculate hash of thread allocate to same queue always.Here we are maintaining order for single thread.If you want order for every log then use time stamp while creating.Writer daemon will collect all log data from all queue in queue pool.